# Fatal error: Function name must be a string Line 11

Tags: php, domdocument

I know there are plenty of these, and that my PHP may be riddled with errors (I'm new to PHP), but I cant figure this one out.... it's citing the "function must be a string" error on line 11:

```
<?php 

$dom=new DOMDocument();
$dom->formatOutput=true;
$dom->load('test.xml');
$searchItems=$dom->getElementsByTagName('title');
$voteItems=$dom->getElementsByTagName('vote');


for ($i=0; $i < $searchItems->length; $i++){
$value = $voteItems($i)->textContent;
$value++;
$name=$searchItems($i);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$resulted = $xpath->query('div[@class="active"]');
$active= $div->$resulted->query('div[@class="content"]');
$names=$active->getAttribute('song');

preg_match($names, "i");

if(preg_match($names, $name )){
$voteItems($i)->length->textContent=$value;
$vote = voteItems($i)->length->textContent;
$results=array($name, $vote);
$txt=($name." scored: ".$vote." votes");
echo $txt;
}
}
?>
```

What this is doing, just in case there's a WAYYY better way to do this is, it checks and XML sheet I have that looks like this:

```
<playslist>
<song>
<source>imgs/Beck.jpg</source>
<title>Modern Guilt</title>
<artist>Beck</artist>
<vote>0</vote>
<plays>y</plays>
</song>
</playlist>
```

It checks for the title, and vote for each song, and stores those.

It then for each gets the value of the vote tag, adds one, then searches the HTML for the `<div>` with the `class="active"`, and then searches that div with active and finds the inner div that has the `class="content"`, then returns that div's "song" attribute.

I then have a preg match to check whether the name of the current "i" in the loop matches the string from the "song" attribute.

If it's a match, that "i"'s  value will +1 to its value. It will then store that name value, and the new vote value as an array for me to check.

After that I'd like to save the XML sheet's new change. (otherwise I would've just kept this in JavaScript)

Any tips, hints, and help would be greatly appreciated! As a newbie to PHP I love to learn more!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$value = $voteItems($i)->textContent;
```

This is incorrect. You're trying to take `$voteItems` and use it as the name of a function.

PHP allows it:

```
function foo() {}
$name = "foo";
$name(); // calls foo()
```

However, that can only work if `$name` is a string. Here, [`$voteItems` is a `DOMNodeList`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php), hence the error message.

From looking at [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php), it seems like you meant to write:

```
$value = $voteItems->item($i)->textContent;
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: So I gave that a whirl, and it shot me this error back: Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::items(). What does this mean? Sorry I'm a newbie. @LightnessRacesinOrbit  Does it help to tell you that in that specific line, I'm trying to store the value between the vote nodes in the xml in $value ?

Comment: @puppies_pidgeons: It's `item`, not `items`. Follow the links I provided to documentation, and study it! Attention to detail is crucial.

Comment: ahh, thank you, I've clearly been staring at my screen just a tad too long